# Websockets for Block.io API giving an error message

Tags: javascript, websocket, bitcoin

I just signed up and want to test out the Websockets API to check on an address balance. Following the API docs, I was trying to see if I could get a proof of concept working, but I can't seem to get past the "success" message. Can someone take a look at this code and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Websocket Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var connection = new WebSocket('wss://n.block.io/:443');
        var message = {
            "type": "account",
            "api_key": "a40c-587d-e9a6-67d3",
            "network": "BTC",
                "type": "address",
                "address": "13qUEUgSZRBqrXUyDghm1JhXMzJyrhA69h"
        };
        connection.onmessage = function(e){
           var server_message = e.data;
           console.log(server_message);
        }
        connection.onopen = function(){
           connection.send(message);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://block.io/docs/notifications

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply but you need to `JSON.stringify` your message. Try something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/bxw3v8c7/

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
var btcs = new WebSocket('wss://n.block.io/');

btcs.onopen = function()
    {
    var addrToMonitor = "1SomeBTCAddress";
    btcs.send( JSON.stringify( {'type':'address','network':'BTC', 'address':addrToMonitor} ) );
    };

btcs.onmessage = function(onmsg)
    {
    var response = JSON.parse(onmsg.data);
    console.log(response); //for debugging
    var amount = response.data.amount_received;
    $('#messages').prepend("<p>" + amount + "</p>");
    }

</script>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do I monitor a testnet?